# Creating a Utility Matrix from CSV File for Collaborative Filtering

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matrix, collaborative-filtering

I have a CSV File Output Like this,
[image]

I need to create a Utility Matrix like this,

[image]

```
r=df.User.unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=r)
```

With the above code I created the User part but I'm Stuck at creating the Rating corresponding to each item for the Users.

Is there any method in Python to do this?

Comment: you can try [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), `df.set_index(['User', 'Item'])['Rating'].unstack()`

Comment: This Works for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas pivot_table to create a utility matrix (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

In your case, it'll be `utilityMatrix = ratingTable.pivot_table(values='rating', index='userId', columns='itemID')`